# Search in List view on publishing page layout

Tags: 2013, page-layout, publishing, xslt-list-view-web-part, list-view-web-part

**UPDATE after trying the OOTB list app:**

I have a strange issue with placing a list view web part on a publishing page layout.

The searchbox is displaying, but when I search it does not load any results (the spinner never stops spinning).

The javascript console spits out:

> inplview is undefined

so I tried referencing `inplview.js`. This makes the error message disappear, but still no luck with loading search results. Filtering and sorting works great though.

Note that this it true both for custom XSLT webpart and for the "App" for the list.

Comment: I found that if I edit the web part and go to 'modify current view' page, click Ok to save the view (without actually changing anything), then the search box will work. But as soon as I publish the page, the search box stops working again.
Modify view will make the search box work.
Publish the page will make the search box stop working. I think this is a SharePoint bug.

Comment: Not solved yet, but as you say, as long as the yellow status row is visible it will work. Seems some JavaScript that is needed for the search box does not load otherwise

Comment: I've done a workaround from codebehind where I call showribbon, but this messes up the Edit-function of the page a bit..

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Robert! I am banging my head on the wall for this!

Basically you don't have to add a code just to show the ribbon by default. Just go navigation and tick `NO` to show or hide command ribbons.

According to the error that i got below, it is referencing to a script outside our domain.

> Webpage error details Message: Script error Line: 0 Char: 0 Code: 0
>   URI:
>   `https://cdn.sharepointonline.com/6274/_layouts/15/sp.ui.listsearchbox.js?rev=SMNOuJrjiX3HzGpk4HWtJg%3D%3D`

And showing the ribbon works well. And this only happens to publishing pages.

Comment: That is one workaround worth trying! To bad we still do not se a permanent fix for this issue!

Comment: I tried this approach, but if the user does not have edit permissions it will not show any ribbon. And therefore it will fail to do the search still

Comment: Has anyone logged this bug with MS yet? Maybe they've fixed it in a later release... we're only on SP1.

Answer (score 3):

This is an issue with InplView not loading on demand when a publishing page is in published state. Still a bug in Feb 2017.

To force the script to  load, add the following script to the page:

```
window.vendor_ensureInplView = function () {
    var typ;

    if (ajaxNavigate.get_hash().indexOf('InplviewHash') === -1) {
        try {
            typ = typeof inplview.RestoreAllClvpsNavigation;
        }
        catch (e) {
            typ = 'undefined';
        }

        EnsureScript('inplview', typ, function() { inplview.RestoreAllClvpsNavigation(); });
    }       
}

_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push('vendor_ensureInplView');
```

Comment: Actually this seems to work OOTB in my environment patched to Jan 2017 CU. Is this not the case for you? I do have managed navigation enabled though..

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is sharepoint OOTB error.. No solution for this

If you want all users to have search enabled you can break permission and give them contribute permision at list level.
Enable the show ribbon ->Always true

Comment: I just gave item-level permissions (`Can Edit`) to the required pages in the pages library.

Answer (score 0):

have you deployed a design manager package to your publishing site?

that can corrupt some of the OOTB content type for publishing sites, and your behavior of it works until published can indicate one of the fields you need is gone. I had this happen with a roll up image in a custom page layout. Worked fine and was visible until I hit publish, then it stopped showing up

if you have, try you webpart and edit scenario on a Plain & fresh site collection.

Comment: No I have not. This was on the standard masterpage, with only some custom CSS files loaded. We have reproduced the issue in a completely OOTB environment too