# ListViewWebPart search times-out

Tags: 2013, search

We have the search box on our **ListViewWebPart** - via `Display Search Box` - and the searches time-out (rarely it works straight-away), with the icon just going around in circles.

Interestingly, if we visit the list view page itself (e.g. by clicking on the **ListViewWebPart** header), the search works every time.

Could there be some script or other issue on the `Site Masterpage` vs the `System Masterpage` that could be causing the problem? Our masterpages aren't too different.

Comment: Can it be the same scenario as I have outlined in this question? http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/70230/search-in-list-view-on-publishing-page-layout

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks - that's it. How do I close this ticket as a duplicate?